# Authenticating user against app engine endpoints

Tags: android, google-app-engine, authentication, google-cloud-endpoints

I am creating my first app engine app and having problems with authenticating the users.

I have followed the https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/consume_android#making_authenticated_calls - seems a bit magical, that I just "setAccountName" and it is supposed to work, but w/e, I guess that it should load the app scopes from Android Audience and then just check if the account name I passed has actually logged into the device.

The API call works, passes the authentication, but sadly - the "endpoints.get_current_user()" function on the backend returns None.

So I kept digging, but I can't seem to find anything on the topic. Best thing I have found is http://blog.notdot.net/2010/05/Authenticating-against-App-Engine-from-an-Android-app - but that's an article from 6 years ago and the author uses HTTP client and nothing related to endpoints libs.

All I can think of would be to follow some "non-endpoints" way of adding "login with Google" to my app and then try to pass the credentials I would get to my API builder, but that just feels wrong, like there should be an easier way to do that.

So, am I missing some step, that was not mentioned in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/consume_android#making_authenticated_calls ?

Actual code (slightly simplified) below:

Backend:

```
auth_api = endpoints.api(
    name='auth_api',
    version='v1.0',
    auth_level=endpoints.AUTH_LEVEL.REQUIRED,
    allowed_client_ids=[
        ANDROID_CLIENT_ID,
        WEB_CLIENT_ID,
        endpoints.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID,
    ],
    audiences=[
        WEB_CLIENT_ID,
        endpoints.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID,
    ],
    scopes=[
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
    ],
)


@auth_api.api_class(resource_name='rating')
class RatingHandler(remote.Service):
    @endpoints.method(
        message_types.VoidMessage,
        RatingsMessage,
        path='rating/getRatings',
        http_method='GET',
    )
    def getRatings(self, request):
        rating_query = Rating.query(
            ancestor=ndb.Key(
                Account,
                endpoints.get_current_user().user_id(), // ERROR! endpoints.get_current_user() is None
            )
        ).order(-Rating.rating)
```

Client:

```
// Somewhere these lines exist
if (credential == null || credential.getSelectedAccountName() == null) {
    startActivityForResult(
        AuthUtils.getCredentials(getActivity()).newChooseAccountIntent(),
        AuthUtils.REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER
    );
} else {
    LoadRatings();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(
    int requestCode,
    int resultCode,
    Intent data
) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (data != null && data.getExtras() != null) {
        String accountName =
            data.getExtras().getString(
                AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME
            );
        if (accountName != null) {
            credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(
                getApplicationContext(),
                "server:client_id:" + Constants.ANDROID_AUDIENCE
            );
            credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
            LoadRatings();
        }
    }
}

public void LoadRatings() {
    // AuthApi was auto-generated by Google App Engine based on my Backend
    AuthApi.Builder api = new AuthApi.Builder(
        AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
        new AndroidJsonFactory(),
        credential
    ).setApplicationName(getPackageName());
    AuthApi service = api.build();
    try {
        ApiMessagesRatingRatedBeerListMessage result = service.rating().getRatings().
        // some stuff done with result, but the Exception is thrown in line above
```

Comment: Are you trying to authenticate the user with a Google+ account or are you trying to do some other authentication?

Comment: All I want is to authenticate the user with Google account and to have the email address available in the backend. I got the account selector to work and set the account name just like https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/consume_android#making_authenticated_calls describes. The API call works, but I have no user object available on the backend which is my goal

Comment: Did you forget to [give the client authorization to access the API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/auth#Specifying_authorized_clients_in_the_API_backend)?

Comment: @saiyr I did not (I have just edited to question to include the api declaration). Also, if I had forgotten to add the client auth, I'm quite sure the request would be rejected without executing the API code and thus without raising the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. When I removed "scopes" from API declaration, it works. I'm not sure how I am going to access user's email / profile yet, but that's at least a step forward.

This issue has been actually brought up before - [How to add more scopes in GoogleCloud Endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32882569/how-to-add-more-scopes-in-googlecloud-endpoints) - sadly, without any answers

Answer (score 0):

You won't have a `User` object (Entity that is) on the backend created for you. You have to do that yourself. For example:

```
@Entity
public class AppEngineUser {
    @Id
    private String email;
    private User user;
    private AppEngineUser() {}
    public AppEngineUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
        this.email = user.getEmail();
    }
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public Key<AppEngineUser> getKey() {
        return Key.create(AppEngineUser.class, email);
    }
}
```

When you create an API method and specify a `User` object like this:

```
 @ApiMethod(name = "insertRecord", path = "insert_record", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
    public Record insertRecord(User user,  Record record)

        // check if google user is authenticated
        throws UnauthorizedException {
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException("Authorization required");
        }

        // user is authenticated... do some stuff!
}
```

The `User` object is an injected type. It is actually: `com.google.appengine.api.users.User`. See "injected types" on https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/paramreturn_types.

What this means is that GAE injects the Google user object if the user provided the correct credentials to their Google+ account. If they did not, then `User` will be null. If it is, you can throw an `UnauthorizedException` the way the above method does.

You can now get things like the User's gmail address among other things if the `user` object is not null. From there, you must store those values in your own custom entity, such as `AppEngineUser` and save it to the datastore. Then you can do other things with it later, such as load it, check if the user is registered and whatever else all by yourself.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I believe that python equivalent of your Java example is:

current_user = endpoints.get_current_user()
if raise_unauthorized and current_user is None:
  raise endpoints.UnauthorizedException('Invalid token.')

The thing is, for me current_user is None (null) and I have no idea what to do to make it not null

Comment: @mpiekarz Are other parameters in your endpoint method correctly passing through and just the user is null?

Comment: @mpiekarz Also, if you are using Android, why not just add a cloud endpoints module and build the whole thing in Java? Good guide: http://rominirani.com/2014/07/28/gradle-tutorial-series-an-overview/

Comment: I have added some simplified codde sample to my question.